# If $R$ is Armendariz then $R[x]$ is Armendariz.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

A ring $R$ is said to be Armendariz if whenever $$f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j=0,\forall 0\leq i \leq n, 0\leq j \leq m $, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}b_jx^j$. Now this result is proved by D.D Anderson and Victor Camillo in their paper "Armendariz rings and Gaussian rings", but I didn't understand fully.
They proved like this way: Take $f(T),g(T)\in R[x][T]$ such that $f(T)g(T)=0$ where $f(T)=f_0+f_1T+...f_nT^n$ and $g(T)=g_0+g_1T+...+g_mT^m$, then he took that suppose $k=degf_0+...+degf_n+degg_0+...+degg_n$ and then write that $f(x^k)g(x^k)=0$, I don't understand this step. Please clarify.

Comment: By assumption we have $f(T)g(T)=0$ as polynomials. Pick any $p\in \text{R}[x]$, then we have $f(p)g(p)=0$ (we evaluate the zero polynomial at some point and get zero).

Comment: The reason we insert some $x^k$ is that we get an expression in $R[x]$ for which we can use that we already know that $R$ is Armendariz. In order to "separate" the different coefficients of the $g_i$'s we have to choose $k$ sufficiently large in terms of the degrees of the $g_i$'s.