# The group ring is not Armendariz

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Why the group ring $\mathbb{F}_2[Q_8]$ is not Armendariz? Any help? Actually, I want to find the zero divisors in its polynomial ring. The group ring contains the $\mathbb{F}_2$ linear combination of the group $Q_8$.

Armendariz ring: A ring $R$ is said to be Armendariz if whenever polynomials $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j=0$ where $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ and $g(x)= b_0+b_1x+...+b_mx^m$.

I want to find two polynomials in the polynomial ring of $\mathbb{F}_2[Q_8]$ such that their product is zero while one of the product of the coefficients is not zero.

Comment: What is the definition of an Armendariz ring?

Comment: Definition of Armendariz rings. 
M. B. Rege, Sima Chhawchharia "Armendariz rings," Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A, Mathematical Sciences, Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. 73(1), 14-17, (1997)
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-73/issue-1/Armendariz-rings/10.3792/pjaa.73.14.full

Comment: I'm not sure that's a well known term, I've never heard it before.  Why not include a definition and some discussion.  Why do you believe this particular ring satisfies the relevant conditions, whatever they may be?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Is $F_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$? Why haven't you copied the definition from your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699211/if-r-is-armendariz-then-rx-is-armendariz)?

Comment: Yes $F_2=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Comment: The letters $i,j$ come from the sky in the definition. Please use some "exist" and/or "for all" in the definition. (And $Q_8$ is "of course" the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group - it does not hurt to mention it, please write a question so that it is valuable and searchable for a community. I understand your problem and the hurry to see that solution, but with your strategy we have now four votes to close the question. Which may have been a good question.) Showing the own effort / ideas is a good idea, you could insert some words without effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a bit of code I found a solution. I will use the notation $Q_8 = \{e,\bar{e},i,\bar{i},j,\bar{j},k,\bar{k}\}$. Let $a = e + k$, $b = \bar{j} + \bar{k}$, $c = e + \bar{e} + k + \bar{k}$, and $d = j + \bar{j} + k + \bar{k}$. Then $ac = bd = 0$ but $ad = bc = \sum_{s \in Q_8} s$. Hence $f = a + bx$ and $g = c + dx$ are two polynomials satisfying your condition.

Have you determined the zero divisors in $\mathbf{F}_2[Q_8]$? Surely you should do this before trying to find all zero divisors in the polynomial ring.

Comment: Why $ad\ne 0$. Because $ \sum_{s\in Q_8} s $ should be zero, I think as the $\mathbb{F}_2$ is of characteristic 2.

Comment: The sum cannot be zero since the elements of $Q_8$ are linearly independent by definition.

Comment: Okay, But I am confused here like, suppose $1(1)$ and $1(-1)$ are two elements. Now, I want to add them. $1(1)+1(-1)=(1+1)(1.-1)=2.(-1)=0(-1)

Comment: The sum of $1$ and $-1$ in any ring is $0$. I don't really understand your computation (specifically the first equality) or what it has to do with the sum of the elements of $Q_8$. I recommend reviewing the definition of the group algebra.